# How to combine guesses/credits

Tags: python

How do I combine my guesses and credits in my python guessing game? for example, if it took me 6 guesses with the first attempt then when I press y to do the game again and it took me 10 guesses how can I get those two to combine for 16 total guesses, same thing with credits (sorry if its a bad explanation) Heres what I have so far:

```
  import random


# this function is for the welcome part of my code or the part where I give instructions on how to play
def game_intro():
    print("          ---- G U E S S I N G   G A M E ----")
    print("\n                 L E T S   P L A Y         ")
    print("""\nThe adjective of this game is to solve guess a 3 digit combination,
and it is your job to guess numbers 100-999 to find that combination!!""")
    print("Credits")
    print("1-4 guesses: up to 60 credits")
    print("5-10 guesses: 10 credits")
    print("if guesses more than 10 no credits")


num_of_guess = 0  # stores how many guess I have made
total_games = 1  # stores how many games I played
done = False  # set done to False
credit = 0


def check_range_main():
    global num_of_guess, credit  # global for getting stuff outside functions
    i = random.randint(100, 999)  # generate number at random
    num_of_guess = 0
    while not done:
        try:  # anything other than a number between 100, 999 gets an error
            user_input = int(input("\nEnter a guess between 100-999: "))
            num_of_guess += 1
            if user_input == i:
                print('you got it right in ', str(num_of_guess), 'tries')
                print(creditScore())
                new_game_plus()

            elif user_input < i:  # if player guess lower than I tell player
                print("To low")

            elif user_input > i:  # if player guess higher than tell players
                print("to high")

            elif user_input not in range(100, 999):
                print("Invalid. Enter a number between 100-999")
                num_of_guess += 1

        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid. Enter a number between 100-999")


def new_game_plus():
    global done, num_of_guess
    new_game = input("Do you want to start a new game? press y for yes n for no: ")
    if new_game == "y":
        check_range_main()
    else:
        done = True


def statistics(new_game):  # statistics for games after players finish
    global total_games, num_of_guess
    if new_game == "n":
        print()
        total_games += 1
        num_of_guess += num_of_guess
        print("P O S T   G A M E     R E P O R T")
        print()
        print(f"total {total_games} games played.")
        print('total guesses', num_of_guess)
        print("your average guess per game is", num_of_guess / total_games)


def creditScore():
    global credit, done
    credit = num_of_guess
    if 1 <= num_of_guess <= 4:
        print("game credits", 60 / credit)
    elif 5 <= num_of_guess <= 10:
        print("game credits", 10)
    else:
        print("no credits")
#print("total credits", )


# def functions matches() that computes and returns the number of matching digits in a guess, you may assume that the
# combination and the guess are unique three-digit numbers.


# def play_one_game():
#     global done
#     i = random.randint(100, 999)
#     while not done:
#         try:
#             user_input = int(input("\nEnter a guess between 100-999: "))
#             if user_input == i:
#                 print("Nice Job")
#                 done = True
#
#             elif user_input > i:
#                 print("input to high")
#
#             elif user_input < i:
#                 print("input to low")
#
#             elif user_input not in range(100, 999):
#                 print("invalid input a number in range of 100,999")
#
#         except ValueError:
#             print("invalid. input a number between 100,999")


# this is where all the different functions go
def main():
    game_intro()
    check_range_main()
    new_game_plus()
    statistics("n")
    creditScore()
    # play_one_game()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Most of the code posted is irrelevant to your problem. See how to create a [mcve] and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72538864/edit) the question.

Comment: Thanks, i will keep that in mind the next time I post something on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Put out the `num_of_guess = 0`  from inside the `check_range_main()`

...

```
num_of_guess = 0  # stores how many guess I have made
total_games = 1  # stores how many games I played
done = False  # set done to False
credit = 0
num_of_guess = 0

def check_range_main():
    global num_of_guess, credit  # global for getting stuff outside functions
    i = random.randint(100, 999)  # generate number at random
    while not done:
```